# Why am I getting Ajax error {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay so I have a node js server running on my local machine and I'm trying to make an Ajax call to my server, the server is accepting the request and the request is executing successfully on the server side but on the client side I'm always getting the error response,

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

My code to make Ajax request is as below,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          crossDomain: true,
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://192.168.1.3:8080/insertintoplaylist?videoid=' + $("#videoid").val(),
          async: true,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(res) {
            alert("response"+res);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert("error!" + JSON.stringify(error));
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Here is the code snippet which will be executed when client makes a request to the path as mention in the url parameter of ajax call,

```
var req = youtube.videos.list({
      id: video,
      part: 'snippet,id'
    },function(err,data,response){

      if(err){
        console.error('Error: ' + err);
      }
      if(data){
        console.log(data.items);
        var dataItem = data.items[0];

        writeUserData(dataItem.id,dataItem.snippet.title,dataItem.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url,function(){
          res.json({msg:'Saved'});
        });
      }
      if(response){
        console.log('Status code: ' + response.statusCode);
      }

    });

function writeUserData(videoId, title, thumbnail,cb) {
  console.log("\nWriting data for video ");
  firebase.database().ref('kidspoemTesting/' + videoId).set({
    title: title,
    thumbnail: thumbnail,
  },function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log("Failed to save data"+err);
      console.log("\nWriting data failed for video ");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Data saved");
      console.log("\nWriting data succeed for video ");
      cb();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you need to return valid json back from the server, can you provide your backend code ?

Comment: Front end code seems fine, You need to look in to how are you writing your data into response. Please provide server side code.

Comment: `crossDomain: true` Are you trying to simulate a crossDomain request within the the same domain/port combo? Because that's what this option tells jQuery to do. If so, you need to ensure your server allows OPTIONS requests and also returns the correct CORS headers when responding. If your request is genuinely cross-domain, this option is redundant. `async:true` is also redundant because that's the default. Have you checked your browser console for any other errors? Does the ajax request actually run? (check your network tab.) Chrome particularly is clear at showing ajax errors in the console

Comment: @ADyson as you mentioned I tried removing the `crossDomain:true` parameter and the error log from chrome browser was like, `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.3:8080/insertplaylist?videoid=bnpfjEHF-NU. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: I have updated my question with my server side code

Comment: for clarity...were you getting this error before you removed the crossDomain flag, or only afterwards? Where is your client page hosted? Is it on http://192.168.1.3:8080, or another domain/port? Seems it must be on another one. In which case your server will need to add the appropriate headers to the response, otherwise ajax requests to it from another origin will not work. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: got it !! 192.168.1.3 was my machine's IP but changing it to localhost worked !, Thanks